# Erro na função CEP

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Olá, tenho uma aplicação em VUE JS, só que quando eu busco o CEP ele não envia os dados para a API, dando o seguinte erro:

> PUT http://localhost:xxx/cadastro-usuario/alterar 401 (Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation)

Quando coloco manual não é apresentado nenhum erro.

Metodo do BuscaCEP:

```
buscaCep: function () {
  if (this.user.address.zipCode === undefined || this.user.address.zipCode.length <= 7) {
    return null
  }

  this.$store
    .dispatch(GET_ZIPCODE, this.user.address.zipCode)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      var self = this

      if (self.address.erro) {
        return
      }

      self.user.address.name = self.address.logradouro
      self.user.address.district = self.address.bairro

      var state = self.states.filter(x => {
        return x.shortName.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.address.uf.toLowerCase()) > -1
      })

      self.user.address.state.id = state[0].id
      self.changeState()

      setTimeout(function () {
        self.cities.forEach(function (result) {
          if (result.name.toLowerCase() === self.address.localidade.toLowerCase() && result.state.id === self.user.address.state.id) {
            self.user.address.city.id = result.id
          }
        })
      }, 200)
    })
}
```

É chamado no @blur.native="buscaCep()"

Metodo que retorna o erro:

```
update () {
  var self = this

  self.$validator.validateAll()
    .then((result) => {
      if (!result) {
        return
      }

      self.$store
        .dispatch(REGISTER_USER_UPDATE)
        .then(() => {
          self.$swal.fire(
            'Sucesso!',
            'Dados salvos com sucesso!',
            'success'
          )
          self.$router.push({ name: 'profile-kennel' })
        })
    })
}
```

Agradeço desde já

Comment: Problema de CORS?

Comment: Não, acabei de baixar a extensão e testar, o erro continua.